# How would one scan another app (like an antivirus app does)?

Tags: android, security

I am wondering how antivirus apps - Lookout Mobile Security, for example - are able to scan other apps to determine if they are malicious. Specifically, what API calls or permissions are used to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do they not just check it's manifest files for certain permissions, then cross check the app names with online databases they hold?

Comment: How do they check the manifest then?

Comment: Not sure if there is an API call, but each app's manifest file is available within it's apk package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the class android.content.pm.PackageManager.

> Class Overview
>
> Class for retrieving various kinds of
>   information related to the application
>   packages that are currently installed
>   on the device. You can find this class
>   through getPackageManager().

Barry